# no video signal from motherboard after Windows Server 2019 install

Tags: boot, video, windows-server-2019

I am pretty new to the server world and I think I messed up beyond repair. I was hoping anyone here could help me out of my missery.

What happened: I decided that my windows 10 home "server" was in need of a real server software so I installed windows Server 2019 (official install + key) on my homeserver which consists of:

1. AMD Ryzen 2500,
2. Asrock AB350 ITX
3. Crucial BX500 2.5"
4. SSD 120GB,
5. 8 GB of DDR4 RAM.

The computer worked fine before installing the server but after installing it, I get zero video signals, no UEFI prompt and nothing seems to happen at all.

I sort of have a feeling that I need VGA for this but the mobo only has 2 HDMI ports, 1 RJ45 port, 4 USB A, 1 USB C and I have no clue what to do in order to get it working.

What I did try was to check whatever the duck happened to my SSD in the meantime. So I dismantled the device, got the ssd and plugged it in. In there were basic windows folders/structure: picture for reference

What's even more odd is the fact that the bios/uefi isn't showing up at all, almost confirming my self that HDMI isn't getting any signal

This is pretty embarassing but I hope someone could help me with what I need to do in order to get a video signal and actually see what's going on, thank you for your time

ps: Even after plugging the SSD out, the UEFI still isn't showing up

Edit: I have cleared the CMOS in the meantime.

Edit 2: I reinstalled a fresh OS in the hopes of it working somehow, neither did that work as expected

Comment: If your motherboard does not have VGA then it's not required.  Something that has yet to be identified is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the Ryzen CPU did not have a dedicated graphics chip. Bought my self a cheap 30/40 bucks gpu card and got visuals again.